# NameError: name 'go' is not defined in sublime text 3 console

Tags: go, sublimetext3

I follow some webpage's instructions to install Sublime Text 3 and use package control to install Gosublime, then change its user-default file:

```
{
   "env": {
       "GOROOT": "d:\\go",
       "GOPATH": "d:\\go\workspace",
       "path: "d:\\go\\workspace\\bin"
   }
}
```

where d:\go is the golang environement I downloaded and installed earlier, d:\go is the workspace I established. Now I want to install gocode. I restart Sublime Text 3, then show console. Wen I enter

```
git get github.com/nsf/gocode
```

It shows:

```
>>> go
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'go' is not defined
```

Below is the complete console log for reference:

```
GoSublime init r17.02.16-1 (0.001s)
|   install margo: no
|   install state: done
| sublime.version: 3126
| sublime.channel: stable
|       about.ann: a17.02.16-1
|   about.version: r17.02.16-1
|         version: r17.02.16-1
|        platform: windows-x64
|            ~bin: ~\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\GoSublime\windows-x64\bin
|       margo.exe: ~bin\gosublime.margo_r17.02.16-1_go1.8.exe (ok)
|          go.exe: d:\go\bin\go.exe (ok)
|      go.version: go1.8
|          GOROOT: d:\go
|          GOPATH: d:\go\workspace
|           GOBIN: (not set) (should usually be `(not set)`)
|       set.shell: []
|       env.shell:
|       shell.cmd: ['C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe', '/C', '${CMD}']
--------------------------------

Package Control: Skipping automatic upgrade, last run at 2017-02-23 14:07:30, next run at 2017-02-23 15:07:30 or after
>>> go
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'go' is not defined
>>> go get github.com/nsf/gocode
  File "<string>", line 1
    go get github.com/nsf/gocode
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But if I run cmd.com and enter same command, it runs ok. What do I miss?

Comment: Sublime's console is a Python console, it's not for executing random shell commands - perhaps you want to use the build system instead?

Comment: Thank, Keith. This is my first time to use Sublime Text. How can I use the 'build system'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Sublime Text console is not a terminal, it's a *python* shell. You can run *python* command, not bash (windows) commands.

As said @keith Hall in his command, to run bash commands, you need some *build systems*. I don't believe that's the solution to your problem, though, since you only want to run this command once, no? If it's the case, you might want to look at `sublimeREPL`, although I'd *recommend* simply using a regular terminal.

Just a quick overview:

Build systems are super useful to run for example `python` program. A really simple build system like this:

```
{
    "cmd": ["python", "$file"]
}
```

will run the currently opened file when triggered.

For more about build system, there's probably no better resource than the [unofficial documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems/basics.html)

Answer (score -1):

You have to add this line `import plotly.graph_objects as go`.
#Python